# финал и не финал

Tags: python, python-3.x

Несколько команд участвуют в турнире по игре «Что? Где? Когда?». Согласно регламенту турнира, в финал проходит половина команд (с округлением вверх), набравшие больше правильных ответов, чем остальные. Помогите жюри сформировать итоговый протокол.

Формат ввода

> На первой строке указано натуральное число N — количество команд.
>
> Далее следует описание результатов N команд в произвольном порядке.
>   Данные о каждой команде записываются на двух строках: на первой —
>   название команды, на второй — количество правильных ответов.
>   Гарантируется, что количество правильных ответов у всех команд разное.

Формат вывода

> Нужно вывести на отдельных строках сначала в алфавитном порядке
>   названия всех команд, вышедших в финал (т. е. команд из лучшей по
>   количеству ответов половины), а затем названия всех остальных команд
>   (также на отдельных строках в алфавитном порядке).

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Пример 1**

Ввод

```
4  
Уважаемые знатоки  
22  
Обожаемые знатоки  
20  
Магистры  
24  
Яндекс.Лицеисты  
23
```

вывод

```
Магистры  
Яндекс.Лицеисты  
Обожаемые знатоки  
Уважаемые знатоки
```

**Пример 2**

Ввод

```
7  
Муми-тролли  
15  
Снорки  
20  
Хемули-ЧГКшники  
24  
Хемули -- не ЧГКшники  
1  
Тофсла и Вифсла  
9  
Морра  
5  
Ондатр  
13
```

Ожидаемый результат

```
Муми-тролли  
Ондатр  
Снорки  
Хемули-ЧГКшники  
Морра  
Тофсла и Вифсла  
Хемули -- не ЧГКшники
```

Вот что у меня есть

```
n = int(input())
s = {}
if n in s:
    for i in sorted(sl.items(), key=lambda x: (len(x[0]), x[0])):
        print(i[0])
print(n)
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Автор, а откуда переменная `sl`? У вас в коде она используется, но нигде не объявлена

Answer (score 0):

Разделите ваш код на 3 части:

- **Получение данных**. Это считывание через `input()` количества команд.

  ```
  title_by_count = dict()

  n = int(input())

  for i in range(n):
      title = input()
      count = int(input())

      title_by_count[title] = count
  ```
- **Обработка данных**. Тут вам нужно обработать данные команд. Например, проверить четность / нечетность количества команд, выполнить сортировку, выборку и т.д.

  ```
  # Половина команд (с округлением вверх)
  need = (n + 1 if n % 2 == 1 else n) // 2

  # Сортировка по количеству ответов от большего к меньшему
  items = sorted(title_by_count.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

  # Получение половины победителей, вытаскивание названия команды и сортировка
  winners = sorted(x[0] for x in items[:need])
  losers = sorted(x[0] for x in items[need:])
  ```
- **Вывод данных**. Вывести в консоль обработанные данные. Например, в цикле на каждой строке или объединив в одну строку вывести сразу.

  ```
  print('\n'.join(winners))
  print('\n'.join(losers))
  ```

---

Тестирование с захаркоденными данными (шаг **Получение данных**):

```
title_by_count = {
    "Муми-тролли": 15,
    "Снорки": 20,
    "Хемули-ЧГКшники": 24,
    "Хемули -- не ЧГКшники": 1,
    "Тофсла и Вифсла": 9,
    "Морра": 5,
    "Ондатр": 13,
}

n = len(title_by_count)
```

Результат:

```
Муми-тролли
Ондатр
Снорки
Хемули-ЧГКшники
Морра
Тофсла и Вифсла
Хемули -- не ЧГКшники
```